# using loop/foreach on args from graphQL's resolvers?

Tags: node.js, graphql

I was wondering if it was possible to loop on "args" of a graphQL resolver ?

I would like to be able to do an automatic processing of arguments, the goal is to dynamically modify the restrictions of an SQL query.

for example :

```
  query  {
  getPerson(firstName: "Jane", lastName: "Doe") {
    someElement
  }
}
```

here, i want to do a SQL query in my resolver like :

```
SELECT * 
FROM persons
WHERE firstName = "Jane" 
AND lastName = "Doe"
```

but when my query is :

```
  query  {
  getPerson(firstName: "Jane", lastName: "Doe", email: "a.b@gmail.com") {
    someElement
  }
}
```

i would like :

```
SELECT * 
FROM persons
WHERE firstName = "Jane" 
AND lastName = "Doe"
AND email = "a.b@gmail.com"
```

so, there is something like ? :

```
foreach different args
   add "AND ... " to my Query's String
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make each argument optional and then check if it was given and include it in your query. But because you didn't gave us your resolver we can't provide the needed changes.

Comment: my goal is to do automatic processing, because if i can have 20 arguments, i don't want to do 20 if(args.element != undefined) { ... } 
anyway, I found the solution, args is like any object in JS, so you can loop on it :
 for (var property in args) {
    if (args.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
      // here, "property" is equal to firstName/lastName etc 
      // here, args[property] is equal to Jane, Doe etc
    }
  }